# Salvar imagem capturada pela webcam de uma página html com javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, fiz uma captura com minha webcam de uma imagem utilizando javascript e fiz um appendChild da url em uma tag div no html. Como faço para salvar essa imagem no meu computador?

**webcam.js**

```
  var player = document.getElementById('player');
  var snapshotCanvas = document.getElementById('snapshot');
  var captureButton = document.getElementById('capture');

  var handleSuccess = function(stream) {
    // Attach the video stream to the video element and autoplay.
    player.srcObject = stream;
  };

  captureButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var context = snapshot.getContext('2d');
    // Draw the video frame to the canvas.
    context.drawImage(player, 0, 0, snapshotCanvas.width,
        snapshotCanvas.height);

    var imgBse64 = snapshotCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

    var image = document.createElement("img")
    image.setAttribute("src", imgBse64)


    var wrapper = document.querySelector('.fotos')
    wrapper.appendChild(image)

    //var arr = document.querySelectorAll('.fotos img')
  });

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})
      .then(handleSuccess);
```

**home.html**

```
<video id="player" controls autoplay></video>
<button id="capture">Capture</button>
<canvas id="snapshot" width=320 height=240></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/webcam.js' %}"></script>
*<div class="fotos">*
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma vez que tens a string em base64 podes fazer o download dinamicamente assim:

```
saveBase64AsFile(base64, fileName) {    
    var link = document.createElement("a");

    link.setAttribute("href", base64);
    link.setAttribute("download", fileName);
    link.click();
}
```